# net use with domain account (where device is local machine) causes UNC mapping to yield Access Denied error

Tags: windows-10, authentication, windows-domain

We have a group of Win10 machines (along with several dozen various Windows servers) on a LAN with a Domain Controller. Most things are controlled through group policy. We are working on a script to access other Win10 machines (and eventually some of the other servers) using UNC mapping, e.g. `\\<hostname>\c$\`. For reasons beyond the scope of this question, we must start by logging into the a local admin account on one of the Windows 10 machines.

At this point, UNC mapping works on the local machine without any further action (as expected). However, we must use a domain account to access the other Win10 machines and servers. We accomplish this through `NET USE` where we setup the authentication with domain credentials. This allows us to use UNC paths to remote hosts without further prompts for login or other authentication-related issues.

**The problem**

This script needs to be able to run on any of the Windows 10 machines, and must be able to access its own paths. If we `NET USE` ourselves with domain credentials, the command succeeds and an entry is created in the net use table with status OK. Unfortunately, once we do this, UNC pathing to ourselves no longer works, and instead gives Access Denied error. I cannot explain this behavior. I have tried this from many of our Windows 10 machines, and in each case, the result is the same. UNC pathing to ourselves works fine (when logged in with a local account via console or RDP), but once we `NET USE` the local machine, we get access denied when using UNC paths. `NET USE` works as desired for all remote hosts, but breaks on the local machine where the script is being run.

I realize we could work around this (in our use case), by simply using standard local paths (e.g. `c:\`...) when accessing local files. But this would make the script much more complicated and create one-off scenarios, along with new code paths that just add a lot of unnecessary conditionals. I would MUCH rather have a single consistent method that works for ANY of the hosts on the network, including the local host where the script is being run.

If anyone could at least get me pointed in the right direction, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks!!